# How can I get an email update for a Google PageRank update?

Tags: email, pagerank

I'd like to be informed when there's a PageRank update for the websites I manage.

Is there a way to receive an email (or a tweet...) after a PageRank update?

Also, ideally I won't be paying to receive this email.

Comment: PageRank is nowadays totally useless, you can forget it.

Answer (score 1):

I think SEOMoz has the feature to trigger emails based on rules you set.  its a paid service but worth the fee if you are serious about ranking your site.